# Passing Data from spring boot to logstash

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash

When I pass the data from spring-boot to logstash, I do not want to have duplicate parse data in elasticsearch[here is the configuration of logstash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avxqd.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can you logstash fingerprint filter plugin and add computed fingerprint to "[@metadata][fingerprint]" as target and assign it to document_id in elasticsearch output plugins